# Associate a specific certificate to a specific local user with OpenVPN

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, certificate

Set up:

OpenVPN 2.3 on centos server.  Multiple clients (windows, osx, linux).  Encyrption using certificates PER device (easy-rsa), and added authentication using the openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so module (username/password).  I am also password protecting the private keys.

Problem:

Anyone connecting with any of the valid certificates can authenticate with ANY of the local users.  The problem with this is that some clients may end up using a very weak password that is vulnerable to brute force attacks.  I know I can simply just restrict the shit out of the client users as a protection to this type of intrusion, however I would rather not be limited to this

What I want:

I would like each local user to be **associated/tied** to a specific certificate.  That way, if Bob's credentials become compromised, and a different user Alice has a very weak password, then the attacker using Bob's credentials cannot brute force via user Alice.

***How can this be done?***

I fully realize that this is "paranoid" security, however it is a feature I believe should be available.  Of course, if associating a cert to a local user is NOT the best and most efficient way, then feel free to suggest an alternative that would accomplish the same goal (i.e. a holder of a specific cert can only authenticate against a specific local user).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `client-connect` script. Amongst other things, it is provided with both username and certificate chain data (so it knows client certificate common name). You can maintain a correspondence between usernames and common names (for example, you may require CN to be equal to the username, but this may require re-issuing of all certificates). The script can use this correspondence to reject connection if something doesn't match.

Answer (score -2):

to keep the total stack under control , you need to start a single openvpn daemon for one of that, creating a single certificate for each user and use a specific port for everyone, then you need to redistribute the pem and cfg file.

But for an enterprise solution it could be better to use l2ipsec linked to WindowsAD and a pre shared key , it's the best choice , so you'll have a sso password solution and no client software to maintain but just configuration by distributing a Pdf with some screenshot :-)
Hope it helps!

Comment: sorry but your first paragraph really doesn't add anything (except for having each user on a separate port, which frankly I don't see how that can help).  I'm not familiar with active directory, therefore I don't know how one can "link" l2tp-over-ipsec to AD.
I would need you to greatly elaborate on your answer in order for me to provide an upvote or possibly mark it as an answer.

Comment: It means that if you want to configure a single certificate for every user, you need to start a openvpn daemon and make  a p-t-p vpn network  for each.
This is the answer.
For L2TP integrated with AD it's more complicated and if you haven't familiar with AD , probably it's not the better choice for you.

Comment: Just to clarify: You are saying that each user must have his/her own specific openvpn instance running, with it's own subnet?  I can see how that will segregate the clients (different openvpn process -> different subnets), however I don't see how that would have anything to do with certificates.  You can have a given openvpn certificate used across multiple openvpn instances/subnets, such as in redundancy scenarios.  In other words, the CA and openvpn server are separated.

Comment: To give an example: Bob uses a certificate bob.crt, and Alice uses alice.crt.  Bob can connect to openvpn instance 1.1.1.1 on port 443, which places him in a vpn pool of 10.1.1.0/24, While Alice connects to openvpn instance 2.2.2.2 on port 80, which places her in a vpn pool of 10.2.2.0/24.  As long as both openvpn instances (separate servers let's say) use the same certs/keys, then Alice and Bob can simply connect to either one.  If Bob's credentials are compromised, he will be able to brute force his way through authentication to openvpn server 2.2.2.2 using Bob's credentials (or Alice's...).